# what is the value taken by value.(entityname)?

Tags: c#, mvvm

i use simple value but i never used value.(entityname).so i have confusion about it.i think value use for taking current value but i did not understand here.

```
  public Tax Tax
        {
            get
            {
                return _taxListing.Tax;
            }
            set
            {
                _taxListing.Tax = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Tax");

                Percent = value.Percent;
            }
        }
```

plz explain it .

Comment: I would do some basic error and equality checking two before assigning `value` to the field.


`if (value!=null && value!=-TaxListing.Tax)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is the special name for the value being assigned in a setter. Its type is the same as the type of the property being assigned, in this case it's `Tax`.

Whatever you can do with any other variable of type `Tax`, you can do with `value`. So if `Tax` has a property called `Percent`, you can access that property as `value.Percent`.

Comment: for example value=10 then **_taxListing.Tax = 10 because of this line_taxListing.Tax = value;** and after that percent=10 because of Percent = value.Percent;this is  right?

Comment: @prjndhi It does not look like `value` could be 10 in your example - it is probably something like `new Tax(200, 0.15)` or whatever is the constructor of your `Tax` class. I mean it's not a simple value, it's a complete .NET object, with properties and methods, and you can use these properties and methods inside your setter.

Comment: ok i got it.that means new instance of tax is taken  by value(**tax(percent,name)**)and after that value.percent and value.name i can use.this is right?

Answer (score 0):

`value` holds the right-hand-side of the assignment that has been called.

For example:

```
myInstance.Tax = new Tax();
```

When this is execuated, the `value` in the `set` block will be equal to the instantiated `new Tax()`.

So when you're accessing `value.Percent`, you are accessing the `Percent` property of the `new Tax()` that was sent to the set scope. This would be exactly the same if the first line was `this._tax = value;` and then you did `this._tax.Percent` instead of `value.Percent`.

If I have a property like so:

```
public int Num
{
    get { return this._num; }
    set
    {
        this._num = value;
        // other logic...
    }
}
```

And I do:

```
myInstance.Num = 41 + 1;
```

The code-flow is as following:

1. The right hand side is executed until a certain value is returned as a result: `41 + 1 = 42`.
2. The right hand side result (42<sup>*</sup>) is set into the left hand side. In this case this is a property, hense step 3.
3. The `set` block of the `Num` property is entered, and `value` will equal `42`.
4. set-block inner-logic is executed, probably setting the value to some private member, etc.

---

<sup>* The answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.</sup>